# Run Stripe < script src > Only When Certain Button Clicked

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement an e-commerce website payment checkout page using Python Flask and Stripe. I have successfully set up Stripe; however, I am now trying to add a "Promo Code" feature, where the user can type in a promo code, click an "Apply Promo Code" button, and a post method will be sent to my backend for the promo code to be verified.

Unfortunately, I'm currently running this script in my HTML:

```
      <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class = "stripe-button" style = ""
              data-key="{{ key }}"
              data-description=""
              data-amount="{{ amount }}"
              data-locale="auto">        
      </script>
      <script>
      document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = 'none';
    </script>
```

What this is doing is running the Stripe checkout script every time a POST request is detected. This is problematic, because my "Apply Promo Code" button also generates a post request:

```
<div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-md-12" style = "margin-bottom: 10px">
                          <input type="code" name="code" id="code" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Code Here" style = "margin: 0 0 10px 0; border: solid 0.5px #0b3c5d; border-radius: 6px">  
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

My question is: instead of running the script src every time a post request is detected, how can I run the script src only when the "Confirm Order" button is clicked and not the "Apply Promo Code" button is clicked? The usual method of detecting a request.form['submit'] value in Python does not work, because the Stripe script listens for post requests and doesn't care about the value of the post request. Here is my backend:

```
    @app.route('/charge', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def charge():
if request.method == 'POST':
    session.modified = True
    if request.form.get('code') and not request.form['code'] == 'SAVE10MORE':
        print('WRONG!')
    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email = session['user'],
        source = request.form['stripeToken']
    )

    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        customer = customer.id,
        amount = int(100 * (session['subtotal'] + session['tax'])),
        currency = 'usd',
        description = 'Payment'
    )
    orders = mongo.db.orders
    has_ordered = orders.find_one({'_id': session['user']})
    if has_ordered:
        orders.update({'_id': session['user']},
                        {'$set':
                            {'name': request.form['name'],
                             'dorm': request.form['dorm']}})
    else:
        orders.insert({'_id': session['user'],
                        'name': request.form['name'],
                        'dorm': request.form['dorm']})
    for key, value in (session['customer']).iteritems():
        has_ordered = orders.find_one({'_id': session['user'], str(key): {'$exists': True}})
        total = int(value)
        if has_ordered:
            total += int(has_ordered[key])
        orders.update({'_id': session['user']},
                        {'$set':
                             {key: total}})
    content = render_template('message.html', ordered = True)
    send_mail('Your Order Summary', content, session['user'], True)
    session['customer'] = {}
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
else:
    try:
        if g.user:
            return render_template('charge.html', 
                                    key = stripe_keys['publishable_key'],
                                    amount = int(100 * (session['subtotal'] + session['tax'])),
                                    tax = session['tax'],
                                    subtotal = session['subtotal'],
                                    months = 2 * deliveries_remaining())
    except KeyError:
        return redirect(url_for('shop'))
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Please let me know how I can stop the script src from running when I click on a certain button! Thanks in advance! This would be very helpful.

Also, my full HTML is as follows:

```
<div class = "container">
  <form role="form" action="{{ url_for('charge')}}" method="post">
    <div class="row cart-body" style = "margin-bottom: 20px">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
          <div class="productbox" style = "width: 100%">
            <h2 class="section-heading"><strong>Delivery Information</strong></h2>

                  <div class="panel-body">

                    <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-md-12"><strong>Student Full Name:</strong></div>
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input type="name" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="John Harvard" value = "{{name}}" style = "margin: 10px 0 10px 0; border: solid 0.5px #0b3c5d; border-radius: 6px">  
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class = "form-group">
                          <div class="col-md-12"><strong>Full Dorm Address:</strong></div>
                          <div class = "col-md-12">
                          <input type="dorm" name="dorm" id="dorm" class="form-control" placeholder="Straus C-12, Dewolfe 20-05" value = "{{loc}}" style = "margin: 10px 0 20px 0; border: solid 0.5px #0b3c5d; border-radius: 6px">
                          </div>
                      </div>      
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <span><p style = "text-align: center"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; Don't know your dorm address yet? You can leave it blank and update it later under My Account <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> Manage Orders.</p></span>
                      </div><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
          <div class="productbox" style = "width: 100%">
                <h2 class="section-heading"><strong>Promo Code</strong></h2>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-md-12" style = "margin-bottom: 10px">
                          <input type="code" name="code" id="code" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Code Here" style = "margin: 0 0 10px 0; border: solid 0.5px #0b3c5d; border-radius: 6px">  
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12" style = "text-align: center">
                            <input type="submit" name="apply" id="apply" class="btn btn-md" value = "Apply Code">  
                          </div>
                      </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class = "form-group" style = "text-align: center"> 
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 button-field" style = "text-align: center;">
              <input type="submit" name = 'submit' class="btn btn-default btn-responsive btn-lg" value = "Confirm Order"></input>
            </div>
          </div>      
      <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class = "stripe-button" style = ""
              data-key="{{ key }}"
              data-description=""
              data-amount="{{ amount }}"
              data-locale="auto">        
      </script>
      <script>
      document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = 'none';
    </script>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Checkout.js shouldn't be an IIFE ( immediately-invoked function expression). Try to turn it into a function not an IFFE which will be called upon button click.

Comment: Hi, that makes sense, but how would I do this? I'm unfamiliar with Javascript and JQuery...all I know is Python Flask, HTML, and CSS. Some example code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include your checkout.js in your question.

Comment: I did not use any javascript in my website. The backend is entirely in python, which you can see above, and all relevant parts of the HTML are included.

Comment: Where is you apply promocode button? What I came to know from this is that you want some post request from promo code button to get generated and afterwards your checkout.js to work. Is it correct.

Comment: So you said you have 2 buttons that are posting same POST request. Putting your HTML above will be helpful

Comment: Hi, I added my HTML file above. The two buttons are the <input type = "submit"> buttons.

Comment: Ok So just change the `<button name="apply" id="apply" class="btn btn-md" value = "Apply Code">` change the `input` tag to `button`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150690/discussion-between-m-ying-and-rajan-chauhan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely need to use Checkout's ["custom integration"](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom), which lets you trigger the popup's opening from your JavaScript code. You could then bind the popup's opening to your "Confirm Order" button's click event handler.